# How to apply Active Directory Auditing with some native tool of Windows server

Tags: active-directory

How we can set some auditing standard in our active directory like if there is any change occur it will give a alert on our mail.
Any creation,deletion, modification in group,computer and OUs 
I don't want any third party tool just want a native solution for that

Comment: There is no native way to do that. You either need a third-party tool or you need to write your own.

Answer (score 2):

Since Windows Server 2008 [there is a possibility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731607%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to audit changes in Active Directory. They are audited as events in Security event log. And you have an option to receive event's details [by email](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx). Also take a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/316778/).